# Simplifying limits while checking $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Show that the function defined by 
$$f(x,y) = \Bigg\{ \frac{xy(x^2-y^2) }{x^2+y^2}, \space when \space (x,y) \neq  (0,0)$$
and
$$f(x,y) = 0, \space when \space (x,y) =(0,0)$$

is differentiable at the origin

I am doing calculus course as part of graduation.

I followed the approach given in answer to following question.

[Can the function $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ be defined so that f is differentiable at the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631190/can-the-function-fx-y-fracxy-sqrtx2y2-be-defined-so-that-f-is-di)

I found $f_x$ and $f_y$. They exist and equal to zero.

I reached the following limit

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow 0} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)||(x,y)||}$$

I couldn't simplify this limit.

Please help me to simplify this limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use polar coordinates:
$$ \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)\|(x,y)\|}=\frac{r^4\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}{r^3}=\dotsm$$

Comment: Are you suggesting to use $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| < \epsilon$  definition to find the limit

Comment: I just answered your question about simplifying the limit. For differentiability, a sufficient condition is  the continuity of partial derivatives.

Comment: @Bernard You've shown the limit equals $0$ and that proves $Df(0,0)$ is the zero linear transformation.