# Prove this function in $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am going through an analysis exercise that asks me to prove $$
f(x,y) = \frac{(xy)^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$
and $f(0,0) = 0$, is differentiable.

The hint suggests to prove that the partials $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous at $(0,0)$. However, this seems quite difficult as they are pretty messy. For instance, $$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{2x^2 y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} - \frac{x^3 y^2}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^3}
$$
and I need to take the limit as both $x$ and $y$ approach $(0,0)$ from any direction.

Any suggestion on how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631190/42969

Comment: The function as given is undefined at(0.0). Throw the book away.

Comment: It's differentiable. I forgot to add that the question also defines $f$ such that $f(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime It looks to me like the limit of $\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ is zero. Re-parameterize $(x,y)$ as $t \cdot \mathbf{u}$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is any unit vector, $t$ is scalar, and take the limit as $t \to 0$.

Comment: @ted yes you're right; using polar coordinates the limit is zero and hence the function is differentiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the function is:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{(xy)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0 &(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$
Let's compute the partial derivatives in $(0,0)$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0 $$
By symmetry, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$$
Now, using the definition of differentiable function, you've to compute the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\langle\nabla f(0,0),(x,y)\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$